# Remove spaces from value in a dictionary

Tags: python

```
def f(a):
    for item in a:
        c = item
        b = len(a[item])
        print('{} {}'.format(c,b))
```

I want to create a function f in python where you can print all keys and lengths of the keys' associated values ​​in a dictionary, for example `a={'A': 'hey you', 'B': 'hello'}` should give us the output:

```
A 6
B 5
```

But with my code I get the output:

```
A 7
B 5
```

Because it count spaces in `len()`, how can I fix this? This is what I have tried so far but it gives me `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
def f(a):
    for item in a:
        c = item
        b = a[item]
        for i in b:
            if b[i] == ' ':
                return b.strip()
            else:
                return b
    print('{} {}'.format(c,len(b)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, use `.replace()`method to replace all the white spaces.:

```
len(a[item].replace(" ",''))
```

```
def f(a):
    for item in a:
        c = item
        b = len(a[item].replace(" ",''))
        print('{} {}'.format(c,b))
```

Answer (score 2):

It is unnecessary to create a new string to count the non-space chars. You can do so directly:

```
def ns_len(s):
    return sum(c != " " for c in s)  # count all non-" "
    # return sum(map(" ".__ne__, s))

def f(a):
    for k, v in a.items():
        print(f'{k} {ns_len(v)}')

>>> f(a)
A 6
B 5
```

Comment: I suppose this is better than mine

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (Note that we do not create a new string)

```
a = {'A': 'hey you   ', 'B': 'hello'}
for k, v in a.items():
    print(f'{k} --> {len(v) - v.count(" ")}')
```

output

```
A --> 6
B --> 5
```